# Insert text to cursor position in rich:editor when click button by Javascript

Tags: javascript, cursor, richfaces

I use Javascript to insert some text at the cursor position in `rich:editor`, but it's not working.

You can see this clearly in this image: [rich:editor](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UQGtS19dOtQ/U1sZDzZeWzI/AAAAAAAAAwk/u8SIbg3JnwE/w830-h386-no/rich_editor1.PNG)

This is the code:

```
<ui:define name="body">

    <h:form id="formEmailTemplate" styleClass="edit">
        <rich:simpleTogglePanel label="Email Template" switchType="ajax"
            rendered="true">
            <s:decorate id="subjectLabel" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Tên mẫu</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="subject" value="#{emailTemplateHome.instance.emailTemplateName}"
                    size="50">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>
            <s:decorate id="buttonCharacter" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Chọn trường</ui:define>
                <a:commandButton value="Chức vụ" onclick="change()"></a:commandButton>

            </s:decorate>
            <s:decorate id="contentLabel" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Nội dung</ui:define>
                <rich:editor id="editor" width="1000" height="300"
                    value="#{emailTemplateHome.instance.emailTemplateContent}" theme="advanced">
                </rich:editor>
            </s:decorate>
        </rich:simpleTogglePanel>
    </h:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change()
        {
            //var val = document.getElementsByClassName("subject");
            var val = document.getElementById("#{rich:clientId('editor')}");
            if(val != null){    
                var value = val.getValue();             
                var position = value.slice(0, val.selectionStart).length;
                var result = value.substr(0,position) + "{chuc_vu}" + value.substr(position);
                document.getElementById("#{rich:clientId('editor')}").value = result;
            }
        }
    </script>
</ui:define>
```

If I apply function `change()` with `h:inputText` it works fine. When I debug with `firebug` in FireFox, I can't get the value in `rich:editor`.

This line of code shows `value` as `undefined`:

```
var value = val.getValue();
```

whenever I change the text `"{chuc_vu}"` to `"#{chuc_vu}"`, so that it's empty text (via Firebug).  How can I insert text in `rich:editor`?

Answer (score 0):

The editor is not just a simple textarea. To handle the the components you should use the JavaScript API, where available.

```
document.getElementById("#{rich:clientId('editor')}");
```

This selects a wrapper div.

To get the text value of the editor you should use this:

```
var component = $("#{rich:clientId('editor')}").component,
    value = component.tinyMCE_editor.getContent();
```

to set the content, use `setContent()`. Note that there will be markup in the text, i.e. your `ccccccccccccccc` will be `<p>ccccccccccccccc</p>`

Comment: Thanks. But get cursor position is not working ! I can't find problem